# How do i set the active tab in PrimeNG tabMenu?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, tabmenu

Where I do declare activeIndex and how to use this variable ?

I have
html file:

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="tabMenuItems"></p-tabMenu>
```

and typescript file:

```
tabMenuItems: MenuItem[];
private stateId: number;
private id: number;
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.tabMenuItems = [
        {label: 'Bar1', icon: 'ui-icon-insert-chart',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', 
             this.id],{ queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar2', icon: 'ui-icon-date-range',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],{ queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar3', icon: 'ui-icon-book',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar4', icon: 'ui-icon-help-outline',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar5', icon: 'ui-icon-public',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        }
    ];
```

**How can i set the active tab, so each menuitem activate the corresponding tab?**

Comment: add [activeItem]="activeItem" => activeItem is which object you selected in the component

Comment: You also have this: `routerLinkActiveOptions: '{ exact: true }'`

Answer (score 2):

[**Documentation**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabmenu)

Set `[activeItem]` property on the `tabMenu`.

Example

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.tabMenuItems = [
        {label: 'Bar1', icon: 'ui-icon-insert-chart',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', 
             this.id],{ queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar2', icon: 'ui-icon-date-range',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],{ queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar3', icon: 'ui-icon-book',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar4', icon: 'ui-icon-help-outline',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        },
        {label: 'Bar5', icon: 'ui-icon-public',
            command: (event: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/#', this.id],
                    { queryParams: {'stateId': this.stateId} }); }
        }
    ];

    this.activeTab = this.tabMenuItems[1];
}
```

In HTML

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="tabMenuItems" [activeItem]='activeTab'></p-tabMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using "**routerLink:**" instead of "**command:()=>**"?

It should not be necessary to assign the **[activeItem]** at all as this should be done via routing automatically. But yet you could assign it manually as follows:

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="tabMenuItems" [activeItem]="tabMenuItems[0]"></p-tabMenu>
```

Refering to this very simple example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-8dcahm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you can see that when using the *"command:()=>"* option it will not have any effect of changing the active tab (e.g. when reloading the page or entering the URL manually, no tab will be selected).
The *"routerLink:"* option works just fine on the other hand.

You can also refer to this post at the forum of [primefaces](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=61303)